# Dynamically Add Custom ActionFilterAttribute to Redirected Action

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, actionfilterattribute

I have a login action in Account controller which redirects to different action based on user rights. We are in a situation where we want to append custom html at the end of the redirected action response. We have a custom ActionFilterAttribute which does the trick but the issue is that we dont know redirected action in advance to register the custom attribute.  So how can I register the custom ActionFilterAttribute dynamically to the redirected action

Thanks in advance

Here is the filter

```
 public class AppendModalWindow : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

            HubController objHubController = filterContext.Controller as HubController;
            if (objHubController != null)
            {
                AccountController objAccController = new AccountController();
                objAccController.ControllerContext = objHubController.ControllerContext;

                if (objAccController.IsContractExpryChkReqd)
                {
                    string strScript = objAccController.GetContractStatusModalWindow();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strScript))
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(strScript);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the Action

```
   [AppendModalWindow]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {
       if(somecondition)
       {
              redirect(dynamic_Url);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one action in your controller, that receives the request, and has the attribute defined on it.  You should then have an if statement in your controller action that implements your conditional logic.  If the logic is extensive, you can have a separate service class with methods for each scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Main issue is that the html is added to the requested action response instead of the redirected action? any thought about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't identify where to redirect the URL in advance, then you can add that settings in your web.config and let the responsible user/admin of your web app to input it.

```
 <appSettings>        
    <add key="Redirect" value="http://path/path/path"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And fetch it in your login Action.

```
[AppendModalWindow]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
{       
   if(somecondition)
   {
      var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Redirect"];
      redirect(url);
   }
}
```